# New to javascript don't understand arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

Ok, I have a SIMPLE HTML doc:

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div id="notInvolved">  This div is static</div>
<div id="thing01"></div>
<div id="thing02"></div>
<div id="thing03"></div>
</body>
```

I want to use an external JavaScript to manipulate the divs.
MY PLAN was the following

1. create an array called divCounter
2. Add the divs by ID thing##
3. Get the length of the array
4. In a for loop goverened by the array size, load in one div at a time, add some data, move onto the next div and add some more data ad nauseam, until I was out of divs.

I clearly don't understand how to build a dynamic array though... (I cannot do this statically I don't know ultimately how many thing## divs I will have)

I thought I could do `var divCounter = [document.getElementById("thing"+ * + *)];`  and that would add the string (e.g `thing01`, `Thing02`).  But that doesn't work.  How do you set wildcards for `getElementById`?  If you can't how can you do it?

Is there a way to accomplish this or am I barking up the wrong tree?  I hate being a newbie....

Comment: can you show the code that you wrote so far?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Try to spend some time on describing this clearly, before describing how you're trying to solve it.

Comment: We are happy to help, but please show your full code. You show only one line of it.

Comment: All arrays in JavaScript are "dynamic arrays".

Comment: "Variables". Also, don't use IDs with incremental values; use classes.

Comment: You don't need to mess with manipulating HTML Elements to just learn JavaScript, the language.  To interact with HTML, use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Speaking very generally (as you have provided very little code to work from) IDs should be something that you should use when things are unique, and classes should be used when things need to be accessible in groups.  It makes much more sense to do something like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="notInvolved">  This div is static</div>
  <div id="thing01" class="affected"></div>
  <div id="thing02" class="affected"></div>
  <div id="thing03" class="affected"></div>
</body>
```

Once you have something that unites them you can use `document.getElementsByClassName('affected')` to retrieve them.  This is probably significantly more meaningful than attempting to retrieve individual elements using a `for` loop or some other construct.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the elements on the page using the wildcard and then use a regular expression to filter the elements.

```
 var all =document.getElementsByTagName('*');
 var r = /^thing\d+$/;
 var test = function(el){
      return r.test( el.getAttribute('id'));
 }
 var elements = [];
 for(var i=0,l=all.length;i<l;i++)
     If(test(all[i]))
         elements.push(all[i]);
```

Comment: you can't use wildcards in `getElementById`, and a regex deals with strings, not DOM elements.

Comment: I know that, see update. I was writing a more general answer. Btw, i'm mobile and the example came a bit late.

Comment: you're going to loop through every element on the page and test their id against a regex? i can't think of a worse way to do this :P

Comment: What do u think jquery does for this query $('id^=thing') ?

Comment: probably a lot of internal optimization and native browser calls i've never heard of. I highly doubt it's a flat loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use classes on the dynamic divs you want to modify, then loop over the results from [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName):

```
var dynamicDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic');

for (var i = 0; i < dynamicDivs.length; i++) {
    // do whatever you want with dynamicDivs[i]
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks that helped, except I cannot get each one to print out by name.  maybe to.string?

Comment: @AharonCharnov im not sure what you mean "print out by name"? The dynamically added divs all need to have `class="dynamic"` on them (or whatever class name you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish.
Anyway, to give you an idea of how to add an element to the array only if it has an ID that starts with with the string "thing", here is a simple example of how to use a for loop, the 
getElementByTagName function and how to access a property of an element of the DOM.
What you really wanted to do (adding an element to an array), is done using the push method of the divCounter array.

```
var everyDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var divCounter = [];
for( var i = 0; i < everyDiv.length; i++ ){
    var currentDiv = everyDiv[i];
    var currentID = currentDiv.id; 
    if (currentID != null && currentID.indexOf('thing') == 0){
        divCounter.push(currentDiv);
    };
}
var res = divCounter.length;
```

Of course, this is for the sake of clarity, I would have approached the problem from a different perspetive, and I would have coded it in a more coincise way.
I agree with the other answers: a class shared among these divs would be best way to select those elements.
An example of the same (with the same too procedural approach) thing is:

```
var everyDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div'), 
    divCounter = [], 
    i, currentID;
for( i = 0; i < everyDiv.length; i++ ){
    currentID = everyDiv[i].id;
    if ( currentID && currentID.indexOf('thing') == 0){
        divCounter.push(everyDiv[i]);
    };
}
```

This is exactly the same, but with the declaration of the variables at the beginning. Since in JavaScript the scope of the variables is the function, not the block of code, is ideal to start a function with a single "var" declaration at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
function load() {
  var divTags = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  var divArray = new Array();
  var j = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < divTags.length; i++) {
    if(divTags[i].id.substr(0,5) == "thing") {
      divArray[j++] = divTags[i].id;
    }
  }
  for(i = 0;i < divArray.length; i++)
    alert(divArray[i]);
}
```